# Keycloak admin client spring boot test not affecting real keycloak

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, keycloak

I have keycloak-admin-client in my app and i would like to test some operations like add user etc. But i would like not to affect the real keyclock application. How to do that? Thanks in advance

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class ProfilesApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Autowired
    private UsersResource usersResource;

    @Test
    void testGetAccountById() {

        UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
        user.setEnabled(true);
        user.setUsername("tester1");
        user.setFirstName("First");
        user.setLastName("Last");
        user.setEmail("tom+tester1@tdlabs.local");
        user.setAttributes(Collections.singletonMap("origin", List.of("demo")));

        Response response = usersResource.create(user);
        String userId = CreatedResponseUtil.getCreatedId(response);

        Assertions.assertNotNull(accountService.findById(userId);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

on my side I have instanciated keycloak as a testcontainer and launch integration test against it like it will not affect any keycloak in production for instance.